# Azure Function Custom Method Properties

Tags: azure-functions, azure-webjobs

I want custom function attribute like

```
[FunctionName("Function1"),Authentication]
 public static IActionResult Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)]HttpRequest req, TraceWriter log)
{
}
```

`[Authentication]` is my custom
`Authentication` implementing `FunctionInvocationFilterAttribute`.
If `Authentication` failed, I would like to directly return `IActionResult` or `HttpResponse`.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that short-circuiting function invocation from a filter is not supported yet. See [this issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues/1314) that tracks such request.